# Kivy Text Filtering Explanation Needed

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I am a beginner in Python/Kivy and I am trying to build a calculator app using this. When reading about the Text Filtering in the Kivy Documentation, I ran into some problems:

As quoted on the documentation, this is the code you should used to to accept only float numbers as input(the comments are the things I think that line of code would do):

```
class FloatInput(TextInput):

pat = re.compile('[^0-9]')                  # Initiate the regex code
def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
    pat = self.pat                          # Call in the regex part
    if '.' in self.text:                    # I dont really understand this 
        s = re.sub(pat, '', substring)
    else:
        s = '.'.join([re.sub(pat, '', s) for s in substring.split('.', 1)])      # I do not really understand this
    return super(FloatInput, self).insert_text(s, from_undo=from_undo)
```

However, I still do not understand how can this piece of code can work. I have some basic knowledge in Regex if that helps. Can you please explain what this class does for me? Also, how can I follow this example to write some more complicated filtering in the future? For example, if I want to accept only Roman Numbers, how can I do this?

Thank you so much for any of your help.

Comment: Perhaps you could annotate each line with what you think it does? This would make it easier to work out and explain what part is confusing or unfamiliar to you.

Comment: @inclement I did try that but I can only understand the obvious things. I tried to break up the things inside the if else statement but the seem too confusing. For example, I don't know what the ' ' in the re.sub do, since I think there should be a method there to do a substitution. Also, is this class reading each character we put in one at a time or it would just read the whole thing?